# Prevent deactivating administrator mode of my application on android device

Tags: android, administrator

I have extended class DeviceAdminReceiver

```
public class DeviceAdministratorReceiver extends DeviceAdminReceiver {
    /**
     * Action sent to a device administrator when the user has requested to disable it,
     * but before this has actually been done
     */
    @Override
    public CharSequence onDisableRequested(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "onDisableRequested", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Intent intentSettings = new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_SETTINGS);
        intentSettings.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        context.getApplicationContext().startActivity(intentSettings);

        //Show dialog window
        return "You shouldn't disable administrator mode";
    }
}
```

When I am trying to stop administrator device of my application dialog box shows up [dialog box to stop administrator mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C109i.jpg) and method onDisableRequested executes before I can confirm the deactivating
My question is how can I close this window without stopping admin mode ? 
I've tried to open main settings when this dialog box appears but settings opens in 10 seconds, so user will have a lot of time to press OK and deactivate admin

Comment: So you want to have an application that is admin forever?

Comment: something like that, but user can easily deactivate it with password